# loop over CSV rows and subtract current row from previous row using python

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
row1
1
3
5
8
```

i need to get the different from one row to its follower row:

```
row1
1  1-1 = 0
3  3-1 = 2
5  5-3 = 2
8  8-5 = 3
```

then get an average on the result `(0, 2, 2, 3)`. Not looking for a straight answer but a start point

Comment: `"Not looking for a straight answer but a start point"` use `open` to read the file

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
# the first row is always 0
result = [0,] + [ int(lines[x]) - int(lines[x-1]) for x in range(1,len(lines))]
#print the array of differences
print(result)
#print the average
print(sum(result)/len(result))
```

Comment: for both of those examples, i am getting this error:

Comment: for both of those examples, I am getting this error: ("ValueError:Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jan-2010,867884). I forgot to mention that I have another row before the the I am working on. Not sure if this is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want a starting point:

```
with open("yourfile.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for index, line in enumerate(lines[1:]):
    number = int(line)
    if index == 0:
        # magic for the first row
    else:
        # magic for a normal row
```

You have to handle the first line different because you can't look behind because it's the first.

## Edit: Solution

```
with open("input.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
output = [0]
header = lines[0]
data = [int(number) for number in lines[1:]]
for index, number in enumerate(data[1:],1):
    output.append(number-data[index-1])
print(output)
print("Average: {}".format(sum(output)/len(output)))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 2, 3]
Average: 1.75
```

Comment: or just start the magic from the second row, it will save the unnecessary `if` (except for the first row it will always evaluate the same): `enumerate(lines[1:], 1)`

Comment: Also, providing `r` to `open` is redundant since it's the default, can just do `with open("yourfile.csv") as f:`

Comment: Can I have the whole solution? I am still having some trouble putting this together.

Comment: true forgot about the header.